# Why fixfoot's fixed footnotes don't accept neither paragraphs nor lists?

Tags: lists, footnotes, paragraphs

Ordinary footnotes accept both paragraphs and lists:

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\newcommand{\alist}{%
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Foo.
  \end{itemize}
}
\newcommand{\twopar}{%
  Foo\par
  Foo.%
}
%
\begin{document}
Bar\footnote{\alist}.

Baz\footnote{\twopar}.
\end{document}
```

But `fixfoot`'s fixed footnotes don't accept:

1. neither paragraphs:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{fixfoot}
   %
   \newcommand{\twopar}{%
   Foo\par
   Foo.%
   }
   %
   \DeclareFixedFootnote{\reptwopar}{\twopar}
   %
   \begin{document}
   Bar% \reptwopar.
   \end{document}
   ```

   fails as soon as `% \reptwopar` is uncommented (hence at least `\DeclareFixedFootnote` accepts paragraphs).
2. nor lists:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{fixfoot}
   %
   \newcommand{\alist}{%
     \begin{itemize}
     \item Foo.
     \end{itemize}
   }
   %
   % \DeclareFixedFootnote{\repalist}{\alist}
   %
   \begin{document}
   Bar% \repalist.
   \end{document}
   ```

   fails as soon as `% \DeclareFixedFootnote{\repalist}{\alist}` is uncommented (hence `\DeclareFixedFootnote` itself doesn't accept lists).

Why such restrictions with fixed footnotes and is there a way to circumvent them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fixfoot expands the body when storing it (with `\protected@edef`).

This means that you can/should protect fragile commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixfoot}
%
\newcommand{\alist}{%
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Foo.
  \end{itemize}
}

 \DeclareFixedFootnote{\repalist}{\protect\alist \protect\begin{itemize}\protect\item a \protect\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}
Bar \repalist.
\end{document}
```

You can avoid problems with `\par` by using `\endgraf` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixfoot}

%
\DeclareFixedFootnote{\reptwopar}{foo\endgraf foo}
%
\begin{document}
Bar \reptwopar.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that this solution also works for adding references to section labels inside the footnote. First create the associated section reference with `\newcommand{\fooref}{Section~\ref{sec:foo}}` and add it to the footnote declaration with `\DeclareFixedFootnote{\foo}{\protect\fooref}`.